# Getting the service page instead of the wcf test client

Tags: .net, wcf

I built a primitive service, (I´m studying wcf), and when I Start without debugging I get the wcf test client instead of teh service page.

I want to see something like:

[image]

But I see this:

[image]

What do I have to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WCF Test client will start automatically if you have service file selected in Solution explorer. deselect HelloWorldService.svc file and try again.

p.s. Also, close opened service files if they are opened in visual studio. (*HelloWorldService.svc.cs* in your case).

Comment: I haven´t created a svc file. I modified Web.config to add a ServiceModel. I'm a newbie and I'm following a book. You can dowload it from here: https://onedrive.live.com/?gologin=1&mkt=en-US#cid=228822BB183339A9&id=228822BB183339A9!234

Comment: I realized that I really don't need it. But I guess that your answer works for those cases you say.